# How to identify between ok and cancel button in inputbox

Tags: vbscript

Hi Hi I have to write a code where if the user clicks enters something in the input box it should proceed further.If it doesnot enter any value it should throw back the same question again again.This i have already achieved,but my problem is when user click on CANCEl it agains asks the same question whereas it ishould exit .I am very new to VB Script .Plz help me how to handle these buttons?Below is my existing code

```
Do while x=0
strAnswer = InputBox("Please enter the file extension  *  For all files:", _
    "File Extension")
If strAnswer = "" Then
        MsgBox"You must enter an extension."

Else

        a=strAnswer
        Exit Do
    End If
Loop


intRow = 2
'strFileName = "T:\public\Madhumita\New.xls"
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = True
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Add()
'objWorkbook.SaveAs(strFileName)
objExcel.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Folder"
objExcel.Cells(1, 2).Value = "File Name"
objStartFolder = "T:\public\Madhumita\Madhu"
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(objStartFolder)
Set colFiles = objFolder.Files
If a="*" Then
For Each objFile in colFiles
objExcel.Cells(intRow, 1).Value = objfolder.Name
objExcel.Cells(intRow, 2).Value = objFile.Name
intRow = intRow + 1
Next

else

For Each objFile in colFiles
m=objFSO.GetExtensionName( objFile.Path )

If m=a Then

objExcel.Cells(intRow, 1).Value = objfolder.Name
objExcel.Cells(intRow, 2).Value = objFile.Name
intRow = intRow + 1


End If
Next
End If 
objExcel.Range("A1:B1").Select
objExcel.Selection.Font.Bold = True
objExcel.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
Sub SaveAs() 
    Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSaveAs).Show 
End Sub 


objExcel.Quit
MsgBox "Done"
```

Answer (score 9):

You need to deal with (at least) three cases - InputBox() returns:

1. an empty value (Empty, vbEmpty) because the user pressed Cancel or closed the dialog
2. an empty string ("") or a string of blanks ("   ")
3. a (hopefully) valid string

In code:

```
Option Explicit

Do While True
   Dim vInp : vInp = InputBox("ee")
   WScript.Echo TypeName(vInp)
   Select Case True
     Case IsEmpty(vInp)
       WScript.Echo "Abort"
       Exit Do
     Case "" = Trim(vInp)
       WScript.Echo "Try again"
     Case Else
       WScript.Echo "Work with " & vInp
       Exit Do
   End Select
Loop
```

sample output:

```
String
Try again
Empty
Abort

String
Work with aaa
```

Sorry to say, but the [Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3yfdhzk5%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) just lie:

> If the user clicks OK or presses ENTER, the InputBox function returns
>   whatever is in the text box. If the user clicks Cancel, the function
>   returns a zero-length string ("").

It should be:

> ... If the user clicks Cancel, the function returns an empty value
>   (TypeName Empty, VarType vbEmpty).

Answer (score 0):

For `InputBox()`, you can use the default value to determine if the user clicked Cancel or if they clicked OK or hit Enter to continue without entering a value:

```
Sub Get_TIN()
   TIN = Trim(InputBox("Enter the provider TIN:", "Provider TIN", "ex. 123456789"))

   If TIN = "" Then    'When CANCEL is clicked because "TIN" will be empty.
      MsgBox "You pressed Cancel. Program will now end.", vbExclamation + vbOKOnly, "Macro End"
      Exit Sub
   End If

   If IsEmpty(TIN) = False Then     'When OK is clicked or Enter pressed because default text will be stored. Next, set TIN to "".
      TIN = ""
   End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm using VBS and my investigation into cancel/ok revealed the following:

Cancel returns an empty string AND a zero length string - same thing you say?, apparently not.

Ok returns a zero length string only.

I use the code below to differentiate.

```
   if IsEmpty(nmbr)  then               'cancel button pressed ?
        nmbr = "x"  
   end if  

   if not IsEmpty(nmbr) then            'ok button pressed ?
      if len(nmbr) = 0 then
        nmbr = "ok"
      end if 
   end if
```

Comment: Cancelling an InputBox returns an Empty Value; pressing OK returns the (possibly empty==zero length) string in the text field; if you ask for a 'nmbr', overwriting the variable with "x" or "ok" may not be a good idea.

Comment: Sorry, Ekkhard et al , it's meant to pseudo code, I should have been more explicit. 
Re the returned values in my original comments, they're what are returned, i.e  IsEmpty(string)  and len(string) = zero are both true for Cancel.