# Multiple condition loop

Tags: vbscript

I need a VBScript loop asking to entered an integer between 1 to 10 including, if wrong symbol or number entered then asking again until the desired number  is retrieved from user.

This is what I tried:

```
Option Explicit
Dim Num

Num=inputbox("Please enter integer number between 1 to 10")

'Checking if entered  value is numeric
Do while not isnumeric(Num) 
    Num=inputbox("Please enter integer number between 1 to 10", "INCORRECT SYMBOL")
Loop

Do while (Num<1 or Num>10)
    Num=inputbox("Please enter integer number between 1 to 10 ", "Number is NOT IN RANGE") 
Loop

Do while not int(Num)
     Num=inputbox("Please enter integer number between 1 to 10 ", "Number is NOT INTEGER") 
Loop
```

does not work: when I enter 3 for example I am getting inputbox saying "Number is NOT INTEGER", when entering a letter I receive error message Type mismatch string, error code 800A00D.

Comment: in what way does it not work?

Comment: when I enter 3 for example I am getting inputbox saying "Number is NOT INTEGER", when entering a letter I receive error message Type mismatch string, error code 800A00D. I need all the conditions in one function or one loop. But when in one loop then it says : can not perform mathematical actions on string. We had very short VBS training

Comment: to Soner Gönül :       It has to be something like that but it is not working either                                                                                                Option Explicit
Dim Num

Num=inputbox("Please enter integer number between 1 to 10")

'Checking if entered  value is numeric
Do while not isnumeric(Num) or (Num<1 or Num>10)
 Num=inputbox("Please enter integer number between 1 to 10", "INCORRECT SYMBOL")
Loop

Answer (score 2):

You need one Loop. For each (variant) input you need to check:

1. is it Empty (User pressed Cancel or X) - Abort
2. is it a blank (zero length or sequence of spaces) string
3. is it numeric
4. is it an integer
5. is it in range - Accept

As in:

```
Option Explicit

Dim vNum, sNum, nNum
Do
   vNum = InputBox("Please enter an integer beween 1 and 10 (inclusive)")
   If IsEmpty(vNum) Then
      WScript.Echo "Aborted"
      Exit Do
   Else
      sNum = Trim(vNum)
      If "" = sNum Then
         WScript.Echo "Empty string"
      Else
         If IsNumeric(sNum) Then
            nNum = CDbl(sNum)
            If nNum <> Fix(nNum) Then
               WScript.Echo "Not an Integer"
            Else
               If nNum < 1 Or nNum > 10 Then
                  WScript.Echo "Not in range"
               Else
                  WScript.Echo nNum, "is ok"
                  Exit Do
               End If
            End If
         Else
            WScript.Echo "Not a number"
         End If
      End If
   End If
Loop
WScript.Echo "Done"
```

Using different variables for the different data types may be pedantic, but should show why you had type problems.

Your

```
Do while not int(Num)
```

does not work as expected because here Num is a number between 1 and 10; rounding off the (not existing) fractional part gives Num again; Num evaluated in a boolean context/as a bool gives (always) True.

**Update wrt comment:**

[Trim](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/LIBRary/c623wz83%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) removes space from the head or tail of a string; WScript.Echo sends output to the console (cscript) or a dialog box (wscript).

**Update:**

As [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29312615/603855) shows, I didn't make clear that pressing Cancel or X (Close) sets vNum to an empty variant, which is different from an empty/zero length string. So it should be treated as indication of the users intention to abort.

BTW: You need to read the Docs, but you can't believe them always (cf. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20539978/603855)).

Comment: Thank You! You explained it very well. Can You tell me please what does "Trim" in "sNum = Trim(vNum)" ? sorry, I don't know how to use mini-Markdown. I am very embarrassed...             WScript.Echo is like Inputbox?

Comment: Thank You! The more I know, the more I understand how little I know.

Comment: Thank You again mister Horner! the only problem, that I am trying to learn HpQTP and it doesn't understand the WScript.Echo so I have to use inputbox instead or something else that I didn't learned about yet.