# Why is this VBS code skipping the first condition?

Tags: vbscript

The following must work in qtp so i can not use WScript.Echo. The following code have to ask for an integer between 1 to 10 inclusive using an inputbox. If nothing entered the it has to give a message "Aborted".

If anything else entered then it has to say what is the problem and ask again for the number until I abort by cancel or by entering nothing. I have the following code but it looks like it is skipping the first condition and goes to the first else in the loop:

```
Option Explicit

Dim vNum, sNum, nNum
Do
   vNum = InputBox("Please enter an integer between 1 and 10 inclusive")
   If IsEmpty(vNum) Then 
    msgbox("Aborted")
    Exit Do
   Else
      sNum = Trim(vNum)
      If "" = sNum Then
         vNum=Inputbox("Empty string")
      Else
         If IsNumeric(sNum) Then
            nNum = CDbl(sNum)
            If nNum <> Fix(nNum) Then
               vNum=inputbox("Not an Integer")
            Else
               If nNum < 1 Or nNum > 10 Then
                  vNum=inputbox ("Not in range")
               Else
                  msgbox nNum,("number ok")
                  Exit Do
               End If
            End If
         Else
           vNum= inputbox ("Not a number")
         End If
      End If
   End If
Loop
msgbox ("Done")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could loop and change the instruction message each time:

```
Dim vNum, instruction

instruction = "Please enter an integer between 1 and 10 inclusive"


Do
    vNum = InputBox(instruction)

    If vNum = False Then
        MsgBox "Aborted"
        Exit Do
    ElseIf CStr(Trim(vNum)) = "" Then
        instruction = "Empty string"
    ElseIf Not IsNumeric(vNum) Then
        instruction = "Not an integer"
    ElseIf IsNumeric(vNum) And vNum < 1 Or vNum > 10 Then
        instruction = "Not in range"
    ElseIf IsNumeric(vNum) And vNum > 0 And vNum < 11 Then
        MsgBox "Number OK"
        Exit Do
    Else
        instruction = "Invalid Entry"       
    End If
Loop
```

Comment: `Is` is reserved in VBScript and does not refer to vNum; `1 to 10` is not legal VBScript; does not terminate on Abort/X click.

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner indeed, appears I've been doing too much VBA today :( - I've edited the answer above.

Answer (score -1):

This is what help says.

> If the user clicks OK or presses ENTER, the InputBox function returns whatever is in the text box. If the user clicks **Cancel**, the function returns **a zero-length string ("")**.

So you aren't testing for a empty, or zero length, string. It is a valid string, just empty.

Also from Help the meaning of `Empty` in VBS, which has nothing to do with what's in a string.

> **Empty**
>
> The `Empty` keyword is used to indicate an ***uninitialized variable value***. This is not the same thing as Null.

### **Update**

**HELP IS NOT WRONG.** InputBox returns a zero length string just like the docs say.

A uninitialized variable HAS A VALUE (for numbers, dates, and strings)

0 for numbers
1899 sometime for dates
and a zero length string for strings (and a string of spaces for fixed length strings).

**HELP IS NOT a TECHNICAL REFERENCE**

Help is a **CONTRACTUAL** document describing behaviour not implementation. As in the COM philosophy.

This is known as LET COERCION. And why `x=65:Msgbox x` works. There are two variables there.

From VBA Implementers Guidelines

> The semantics of Empty Let-coercion depend on the destination’s declared type: Source
>
> Any numeric type - The result is 0.
>
> Boolean - The result is False.
>
> Date - The result is 12/30/1899 00:00:00.
>
> String - The result is a 0-length string.
>
> String * length - The result is a string containing length spaces.
>
> Any class or Object - Runtime error 424 (Object required) is raised. -
>
> Any other type except Variant - Runtime error 13 (Type mismatch) is raised.

Comment: @Serenity - the Docs lie (http://stackoverflow.com/a/20539978/603855), so your answer is not correct.

Comment: I don't read SO. I only read docs. Try this program `A = InputBox("hi"):Msgbox Vartype(A) & " " & IsEmpty(A) & " " & IsNull(A)`.

Comment: @Serenity - The program returns "0 True False" **if Cancel or X is pressed**. VarType 0 is Empty Variant, not String.

Comment: @Serenity - you shouldn't insist on false info.

Comment: I think I explained in my edit to my answer why your old post is wrong.