# How to vbs Ok, Cancel and X to work correctly in a .vbs script?

Tags: vba, vbscript

Hello everyone i put together this neat little script that quiz's the knowledge of the user on there Star Trek knowledge the script executes perfectly, but when hitting either OK, Cancel or X the questions are still answered as correct. I do know i need a vbCancel set in there somewhere but not sure about how to add it to the script.

```
'***********************************************************************
'Script Name: StarTrekQuiz.vbs
'Author: CharlesP
'Created: 03/31/15
'Description: This script creates a Star Trek Quiz game.
'***********************************************************************

'Perform script initialization activities
Option Explicit 
Dim intPlayGame, strSplashImage, intNumberCorrect, strFederationRank 
Dim objFsoObject, objQuestionDict, strAnswer, strQuestion

Const cTitlebarMsg = "The Star Trek Quiz Game" 
Set objQuestionDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") 
objQuestionDict.Add "What was the Science Officer's name in the original Star Trek series?", "spock" 
objQuestionDict.Add "What Star Trek villain appeared in both the original series and a Star Trek movie?", "khan" 
objQuestionDict.Add "What was the numeric designation of Voyager's on-board Borg?", "7" 
objQuestionDict.Add "Name the only Star Trek character to regularly appear on two series and at least two Star Trek movies?", 

"worf" 
objQuestionDict.Add "What is the last name of your favorite Captain?", "kirk picard sisco janeway archer"
objQuestionDict.Add "Who directed the first Star Trek movie?", "Robert Wise"
objQuestionDict.Add "In what Star Trek TOS episode did the tribbles FIRST appear?", "The Trouble With Tribbles"
objQuestionDict.Add "In what episode of Star Trek TNG did the Enterprise transport samples of Plasma Plague for medical 

research?", "The Child"
objQuestionDict.Add "Who voices the computer in TNG?", "Majel Barrett"
objQuestionDict.Add "In TOS ~The Ultimate Computer~ who was the captain of the U.S.S. Excalibur?", "Captain Harris"

'Start the user's score at zero 
intNumberCorrect = 0 

'Display the splash screen and ask the user if he or she wants to play 
strSplashImage = space(11) & "********" & vbCrLf & _ 
  "  ******************" & space(20) & "**************************" & _ 
  space(15) & vbCrLf & "*" & space(30) & "*" & space(18) & _ 
  "**" & space(39) & "*" & vbCrLf & "  ******************" & _ 
  space(20) & "*************************" & vbCrLf & space(31) & _ 
  "******" & space(26) & "***" & vbCrLf & _ 
  space(34) & "******" & space(22) & "***" & vbCrLf & _ 
  space(37) & "******" & space(17) & "***" & vbCrLf & _     
  space(26) & " ****************************" & vbCrLf & _ 
  space(26) & "*******************************" & vbCrLf & _ 
  space(26) & "******************************" & vbCrLf & _ 
  space(26) & " ****************************" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _ 
  "Would you like to boldly go where no one has gone before?" 

'Ask the user to play 
intPlayGame = MsgBox(strSplashImage, 36, cTitlebarMsg) 
If intPlayGame = vbYes Then 'User elected to play the game 
    For Each strQuestion In objQuestionDict 
    strAnswer = InputBox(strQuestion, cTitlebarMsg)
    If Trim(strAnswer) <> "" Then
        If Instr(strAnswer, objQuestionDict(strQuestion)) Or Instr(objQuestionDict(strQuestion), strAnswer) Then 
            MsgBox "Correct" 
            intNumberCorrect = intNumberCorrect + 1 
        Else  
            MsgBox "Nice try.  The answer I was looking for was " & objQuestionDict(strQuestion) 
        End If 
    End If
Next 
Select Case intNumberCorrect 
  'User got 10 of 10 answers right 
  Case 10 : strFederationRank = "Fleet Admiral"    
  'User got 9 of 10 answers right 
  Case 9 : strFederationRank = "Admiral" 
  'User got 8 of 9 answers right 
  Case 8 : strFederationRank = "Vice Admiral" 
  'User got 7 of 8 answers right 
  Case 7 : strFederationRank = "Rear Admiral-Upper Hall" 
  'User got 6 of 7 answers right 
  Case 6 : strFederationRank = "Rear Admiral-Lower Hall" 
  'User got 5 of 5 answers right 
  Case 5 : strFederationRank = "Captain" 
  'User got 4 of 5 answers right 
  Case 4 : strFederationRank = "Commander"    
  'User got 3 of 5 answers right 
  Case 3 : strFederationRank = "Lieutenant-Commander" 
  'User got 2 of 5 answers right 
  Case 2 : strFederationRank = "Lieutenant" 
  'User got 1 of 5 answers right 
  Case 1 : strFederationRank = "Lieutenant Junior Grade" 
  'User did not get any answers right 
  Case 0 : strFederationRank = "Ensign" 
End Select 
MsgBox "You answered " & intNumberCorrect & " out of 10 correct." & _ 
  vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Your Star Fleet rank is : " & _ 
  strFederationRank, , cTitlebarMsg 
Else 'User doesn't want to play 
    MsgBox "Thank you for taking the Star Trek Quiz" & _ 
    vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Live long and prosper!", , cTitlebarMsg  
    WScript.Quit()
End If
```

Any help would be much appreciated thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike `MsgBox` function or `Popup` method, `InputBox` function has no `vbCancel` option.

> If the user clicks <kbd>OK</kbd> or presses <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, the
>   `InputBox` function returns whatever is in the text box. If the user
>   clicks <kbd>Cancel</kbd> or <kbd>×</kbd>, the function returns a
>   zero-length string (`""`).

Strictly speaking, above [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3yfdhzk5(v=vs.84).aspx) quotation is not right. If the user
clicks <kbd>Cancel</kbd> or <kbd>×</kbd> button or presses <kbd>Esc</kbd> key, the function returns `Empty` value (the same as if a variable is uninitialized.

Next code snippet could help.

```
  ' Ask the user to play 
intPlayGame = MsgBox(strSplashImage, vbYesNo + vbQuestion, cTitlebarMsg) 

Dim WshShell                  'prepare for POPUP method
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

If intPlayGame = vbYes Then 'User elected to play the game 
    For Each strQuestion In objQuestionDict 
        strAnswer = InputBox(strQuestion, cTitlebarMsg)
        If VarType( strAnswer)=0 Then
            intPlayGame = WshShell.Popup( _
              "Cancel pressed or window closed. Continue?", 7, _
                  cTitlebarMsg, vbYesNo + vbQuestion)
            If not intPlayGame = vbYes Then Wscript.Quit
            strAnswer=""
        End If
        if strAnswer="" Then strAnswer="???"
        If Instr(1, strAnswer, objQuestionDict(strQuestion), vbTextCompare) _
            Or Instr(1, objQuestionDict(strQuestion), strAnswer, vbTextCompare) Then 
            MsgBox "Correct" 
            intNumberCorrect = intNumberCorrect + 1 
        Else 
            MsgBox strAnswer & " Nice try.  The answer I was looking for was " & objQuestionDict(strQuestion) 
        End If 
    Next 
Select Case intNumberCorrect
```

Predefined MsgBox / Popup Constants

```
'                         Button Type
' vbOKOnly              0 Display OK button only.
' vbOKCancel            1 Display OK and Cancel buttons.
' vbAbortRetryIgnore    2 Display Abort, Retry, and Ignore buttons.
' vbYesNoCancel         3 Display Yes, No, and Cancel buttons.
' vbYesNo               4 Display Yes and No buttons.
' vbRetryCancel         5 Display Retry and Cancel buttons.

'                         Icon Type
' vbCritical           16 Display Critical Message icon.
' vbQuestion           32 Display Warning Query icon.
' vbExclamation        48 Display Warning Message icon.
' vbInformation        64 Display Information Message icon.

'                         Default Button: MsgBox Function only 
' vbDefaultButton1      0 First button is the default.
' vbDefaultButton2    256 Second button is the default.
' vbDefaultButton3    512 Third button is the default.
' vbDefaultButton4    768 Fourth button is the default.

'                         Modality of the box: MsgBox Function only
' vbApplicationModal    0 Application modal. The user must respond to the message box before continuing work in the current application.
' vbSystemModal      4096 System modal. On Win16 systems, all applications are suspended until the user responds to the message box. On Win32 systems, this constant provides an application modal message box that always remains on top of any other programs you may have running. 

'                  Return Value
' vbOK      1      OK
' vbCancel  2      Cancel
' vbAbort   3      Abort
' vbRetry   4      Retry
' vbIgnore  5      Ignore
' vbYes     6      Yes
' vbNo      7      No       
' vbTrue   -1      nSecondsToWait elapsed, the user did not click a button before 
'
```

**Edit**:

@Ekkehard.Horner is right as `CStr(VarType(strAnswer)) & TypeName(strAnswer)` returns `0Empty` if clicked <kbd>Cancel</kbd> or <kbd>×</kbd> in response to an `InputBox`. My resource: [MSDN VBScript language reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3yfdhzk5(v=vs.84).aspx). 
But it's a faultfinder's quibble only here because by the same MSDN: [how expressions are compared](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9hck4s70(v=vs.84).aspx): if one expression is `Empty` and the other is a string, then perform a string comparison, using a zero-length string (`""`) as the `Empty` expression.

Thus, `If strAnswer = "" ...` comparison gives the same result regardless of `strAnswer` variable

- is an empty string `""`, or
- is uninitialized, or is explicitly set to `Empty`.

However,  we could test `VarType(strAnswer)` and allow a user to correctly terminate the quiz uncomplete (see update in code snippet, used `Popup` method).

Comment: That is definitely a step in the right direction but after the first 5 questions it goes right back to the same thing. And is there any way to script the X to exit the script completely.

Comment: Clicking Cancel/X does **not** return a zero-length string, but an empty variant cf. http://stackoverflow.com/a/29163379/603855

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner you are right but that _nuance_ did not matter in this case for a string comparison only. Now used to exit the script completely, here matters  (see my edit).

Answer (score 0):

Clicking on cancel returns empty string in Inputbox.

So, check if the answer is "".

```
For Each strQuestion In objQuestionDict 
    strAnswer = InputBox(strQuestion, cTitlebarMsg)
    If Trim(strAnswer) <> "" Then
        If Instr(strAnswer, objQuestionDict(strQuestion)) Or Instr(objQuestionDict(strQuestion), strAnswer) Then 
            MsgBox "Correct" 
            intNumberCorrect = intNumberCorrect + 1 
        Else 
            MsgBox "Nice try.  The answer I was looking for was " & objQuestionDict(strQuestion) 
        End If 
    End If
Next
```

Comment: I will try this and see what happens

Comment: @Chuck.Norris, as per this, if the user clicks on cancel or X, we show the next question immediately. We do not count it as correct answer. This behavior  looks ok to me.

Comment: Clicking Cancel/X does **not** return a zero-length string, but an empty variant cf. http://stackoverflow.com/a/29163379/603855

Comment: @Vinoth S I totally understand that and I am ok with this but for some reason after the 5th question the script stops doing that and reverts to if you click Ok, Cancel, or X it says the answer is correct.

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner I will try this as soon as I get to my computer. Always a pleasure speaking with you sir.

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner still getting the same results in the sense that after the fifth question the script reverts back to the "Correct" Message box wether the user hits OK, Cancel, or X.

Comment: Can you post the code you have now? I do not see any issues in mine

Comment: @Vinoth S your code worked i was missing If Trim(strAnswer) <> "" Then aspect of the code once i added that it worked flawlessly thank you the only issue with it is that it does not give you the MsgBox with the answer i was looking for if the hit Ok, Cancel, or X.

Comment: @Vinoth S i corrected two typos i was having this Script is finished thank you all for all your help.