# Vbscript type mismatch error apparently not justifiable

Tags: vbscript

I'm trying to figure out why I would get this error for the code below. I've searched on the web for possible causes but I couldn't find. Please have a look:

```
Dim descr, code

If WScript.Arguments.Count = 0 Then
    Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    objShell.ShellExecute "wscript.exe", Chr(34) & Script.ScriptFullName Chr(34) & " Run", , "runas", 1
Else
    descr = InputBox("restore point description","Crepo")
    If (descr) Then
        code = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.root default:Systemrestore").CreateRestorePoint (descr, 0, 100)
        If (code) Then
            Msgbox "System Restore Point not created (" & code & ") !", 48, "Crepo"
        Else
            Msgbox "System Restore Point successfully created", 64, "Crepo"
        End If
    End If
End If
```

At runtime, if I input anything, i.e. `qwerty` I get this error:
Line: 8
Char: 2
Error: Type mismatch: '[string: "qwerty"]'
Code: 800A000D
From my researches, return type of `InputBox` is `string` and `CreateRestorePoint` first argument is also `string`. In fact, it works if I call `InputBox` directly as the argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `If (descr) Then` try `If (Not IsNull(descr)) Then`.
You <s>may</s> also want to check for empty strings too: `If (Not IsNull(descr) and descr <> "") Then`. In fact, as pointed out in the other answer, since the VBScript [InputBox function docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3yfdhzk5%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) note that *If the user clicks Cancel, the function returns a **zero-length string ("")*** you definitely need to check for an empty/zero-length string.

Comment: Thank you. It works. I'm new to vb. But aren't empty string and null string the same?

Comment: Null and empty strings are not he same thing. Null/Nothing means the variable references/points to, well, nothing :) An empty string means the variable references the value, but the value has zero characters.

Comment: As @EkkehardHorner has pointed out `InputBox()` never returns Null, it can return either a string or `vbEmpty` VarType Constant.

Answer (score 1):

The If clause needs a boolean (not a string):

```
>> descr = "qwerty"
>> If (descr) Then WScript.Echo "nonsense"
>>
Error Number:       13
Error Description:  Type mismatch
```

InputBox returns a string or an empty value (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20539978/603855)), but **never** Null.