# VBScript Error Type mismatch Code 800A000D

Tags: vbscript

I copied a script to create a Signature for Outlook and adjusted it to my needs, which surprisingly works quite well, unless for one thing. When I try to insert the Mobile Phone number out of the Active Directory, which is in the format +49 173 ####### I get following error:

[image: Error 800A000D]

here is the code I use for it:

```
strMobile = objUser.Mobile

if (strMobile) Then objSelection.TypeText "Mobil: " & strMobile
```

It does work when I delete the 2 blanks in the mobile phone number and it does work when I delete the "if then" query in front of objSelection..., which I don't understand at all, but neither is an option in my case.
The "if then" query is because not everyone has a mobile phone number entry and without the blanks it looks horrible. I'm sure there must be a solution to this but I couldn't find it so far.

Comment: Please don't post errors as images and especially not when they are non-English. All errors should be clear and provided in English. Please see [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) and [Advice for non-native English speakers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/291362).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vbscript type mismatch error apparently not justifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33351565)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem, I believe, is the `if (strMobile) Then`.  It probably needs to be restated as `If Trim(strMobile) <> ""` assuming that you are testing for a non-empty string. The type error occurs because `strMobile` cannot be evaluated as a Boolean in VBScript because it's a string.

Comment: While this is *probably* the answer, answering poorly asked questions just leads to more of the same and doesn’t help the [so] community maintain a degree of quality. These questions are not just for the original poster but for others looking for the answer to a similar question. As this question is poorly formatted and in part non-English is currently doesn’t fulfil that criteria and should to left to be improved or removed before attempting to answer.

Comment: Thanks user9601310, that's exactly what I needed and thanks to your explanation I also know why the type error occurred in the first place. :)