# How do you end a vbs file if the an entry is not given

Tags: vbscript

How would I end the vbs file if the password is not entered, it continues if "Okay" is clicked.
I want this to end if nothing is entered.
is that possible?

```
    If InputBox("Please enter the passcode.", "Restricted access") = "Passcode" Then MsgBox "Correct passcode. You may continue.

 Dim speaks, speech
    name=inputbox("What's your name?", "WELCOME")
    speaks=("Welcome ") + name
    Set speech=CreateObject("sapi.spvoice")
    speech.Speak speaks
```

Comment: See 'https://stackoverflow.com/a/20539978/6038551'. I assume you know about 'WScript.Quit'.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Do you mean something like that?

```
    Dim strPassword As String
    strPassword = InputBox("Please enter the passcode.", "Restricted access") & ""
If strPassword = "Passcode" then
   MsgBox "Correct passcode. You may continue."
   Dim speaks, speech
    name=inputbox("What's your name?", "WELCOME")
    speaks=("Welcome ") + name
    Set speech=CreateObject("sapi.spvoice")
    speech.Speak speaks
else 
    WScript.Quit
endif
```

Comment: 'Dim strPassword As String' is not VBScript; the problem is how to check for empty input/cancel.